# Error Loading VB 6 Project In Windows 7 - MSComCtl2

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, visual-studio, visual-basic, vb6

I can't open my VB6 project on any Windows 7 machine. I did a clean OS install on a machine.  The OS is Windows 7 Pro SP1 32 bit. All I have installed on this machine is VB6 Enterprise and Office 2007 Enterprise. When I try to open my VB6 project I receive this error:

[image: Error Message]

**This is what the log files give me for the error:**

Line 120: Class MSComCtl2.DTPicker of control dtToDate was not a loaded control class.

Line 132: Class MSComCtl2.DTPicker of control dtFromDate was not a loaded control class.

**What I have tried so far to fix the issue:**

Ran VB6 as Admin

Downloaded MSComt2 cab file and replaced the .ocx and .dll in system32

Ran regsvr32 and registered the .dll

Reinstalled VB6 Enterprise and SP 6

I have tried this on three different Windows 7 machines, and have had the same error.

Comment: If the compatability mode does not work.  I would just enable `Windows XP` mode.  Based on the error its pretty clear the project itself might have problems or your missing a required component.

Comment: @Ramhound XP Mode is not an option. The date time picker is there, when I run the .exe the components show up on the forms. So the required components are not missing. I just can't open the project to make changes.

Comment: Have you confirmed the problem simply isn't the project itself? This is what a virtual machine can be used for. You can get a FREE Windows XP virtual machine from Microsoft, install the additional software you require, in order to make sure its NOT the project itself.  You could also in theory just use the provided `Windows XP` Windows XP license also.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I have confirmed that the project is fine, it opens on any Windows XP machine that we have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the VBP file with notepad, and find the lines with the component(s) in them, and delete them. Start the project and re-add them in Visual Basic. Probably the CLSID's are wrong for your machine

Also check the version of the files you are registering with the line in your VBP file to see if they are the same

Comment: I have tried this on three different Windows 7 machines now and get the same issues.

Comment: This is the only solution that occur on my mind at the moment. I'll post another if I think of any

Comment: No problem ... I know how these issues can be annoying :(

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. 
When I ran the VB in admin mode it was solved.